# Rendering individual points in Shiny through leaflet not working

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to give the user a choice to cluster map points rendered in leaflet in Shiny, or display the raw signals.

Clustering works, but rendering individual points doesn’t.

Code:

ui.R side:

```
tabPanel('map',
           fluidRow(
             column(2, actionButton('plot_map', 'render'))
           )
           , checkboxInput('map_cluster', label = 'cluster faults', value = TRUE)
           , sliderInput('map_maxClusterRadius', 'max cluster radius', min = 10, max = 300, step = 5, value = 80)
           , leafletOutput("fault_map")
)
```

server.R side:

```
output$fault_map <- renderLeaflet({
    input$plot_map # a button to execure

    plot_data <- data.table(matrix(rpois(lambda = 50, 500), ncol = 5))


    withProgress(message = 'rendering...', {
      map <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.HOT" # "Stamen.TonerBackground"
                                            # , options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      )

      if (input$map_cluster){
        map <- map %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = plot_data, lng = plot_data[, V1], lat = plot_data[, V2], radius = 2.5,
                           color = 'red'
                           , clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(removeOutsideVisibleBounds = TRUE
                                                                   , spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
                                                                   , showCoverageOnHover = TRUE
                                                                   , maxZoom = 9
                                                                   , popup = ~V4
                                                                   , maxClusterRadius = input$map_maxClusterRadius)
          )
      } else {
        map <- map %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = plot_data, lng = plot_data[, V1], lat = plot_data[, V2], radius = 1,
                           color = 'red'
#                            , clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(removeOutsideVisibleBounds = TRUE
#                                                                    , spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
#                                                                    , showCoverageOnHover = TRUE
#                                                                    , maxZoom = 9
#                                                                    , popup = ~V4
#                                                                    , maxClusterRadius = input$map_maxClusterRadius)
          )

      }



      return(map)
    })
  })
```

With and without the checkbox selection:

[image: clustering works]

[image: rendering individual points doesn’t work]

Also, stuff like polygon preview (a preview of the area covered by a cluster) doesn’t work. This sort of thing:

[image: polygon preview]

All of this was working about a month ago. The only change I did was move to ShinyBS, but as you can see above, it doesn’t work even if I don’t use ShinyBS.

Trying to use similar code to render from RStudio produces a plot showing individual points.

Thanks!